# Apache Camel Route Template

Tags: java, templates, routes, apache-camel

I'm trying to use the Camel Route templates by creating them from properties file. I'm following the example on the official web page [route template example](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples/camel-example-routetemplate), but the code doesn't compile:

```
public class MyRouteTemplates extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // create a route template with the given name
    routeTemplate("myTemplate")
        // here we define the required input parameters (can have default values)
        .templateParameter("name")
        .templateParameter("greeting")
        .templateParameter("myPeriod", "3s")
        // here comes the route in the template
        // notice how we use {{name}} to refer to the template parameters
        // we can also use {{propertyName}} to refer to property placeholders
        .from("timer:{{name}}?period={{myPeriod}}")
            .setBody(simple("{{greeting}} ${body}"))
            .log("${body}");
}
```

More in details, where is defined `routeTemplate`?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: I'm using Camel 3.4.4...

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick: route templates are part of the 3.6.0 snapshot!

Comment: You are right about `3.6`, but this feature have been implemented one minor version before - in `3.5`. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14963